# Why does File Explorer hang frequently in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

Why does File Explorer hang frequently in Windows 8 when I am browsing through a folder containing about 20-30 files and folders?

The program hangs for around ~5-10 seconds like it is still processing. This happens with almost every start. This was not the case before, with Windows 7.

The machine in question is running on an Intel Core i3 3GHz processor with 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Is it trying to create thumbnail previews?

Comment: more important than your CPU or RAM: Spinning HDD or SSD?!

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Not trying to create thumbnils, not even consuming much more memory as per task manager

Comment: @klyonrad Running on HDD, could be the spinning issue, but was not the case with Windows 7 as well as with just 20-30 folders it must not be the case

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Is E: your CD\DVD\BLURAY drive? If not, what drive is it if you only have one HDD. Is it a partition?

Comment: @harrymc Haven't tried with Safe Mode yet, will let you know soon.

Comment: @Thraka This happens with some of the folders of the one and only HDD available in my system. Also this happens with folders irrespective of Drive Letter.

Comment: @DOM you should clarify your comment down below because you say: 2. Problem is in a different drive then boot drive (C: is a boot drive, problem is in E: drive)  ... Meaning the problem is only on E:

Comment: Do you have any network locations under This PC? I had a Plex server causing Explorer to freeze until I disconnected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the Windows Defender is the cause of this Explorer slowdown. Here is what I get when scrolling through the Explorer:

[image]

Look if you also have this high CPU usage. if yes, disable Defender and install a different AV tool.

Comment: You are right my friend, although option for defender is yet to be discovered.

Comment: Start regedit, go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender** and set the key **DisableAntiSpyware** to **1**.

Comment: Permissions are denied -- looks like WinDefender locks down permissions on its own registry keys....

Comment: @RossPresser you have to take ownership of the key and change the permissions.

Comment: Eventually I turned off Defender completely. It still didn't stop File Explorer slowdown/hangs in Windows 8.1 on this machine.

Comment: @RossPresser create a dmp (with taskmgr) when you have the hang. Open it with Windbg, setup symbols (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) and run **!analyze -v -hang**. Which 3rd party dlls show up?

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/AvjeewAD) is the output from `!analyze -v -hang`:

Comment: It looks like `Easyhook64.dll`, the top item in the thread stack, is being used by 1UP Industries' Bins. I will be very sad if I have to give up Bins.

Comment: @RossPresser What is this tool doing? Why does it need to install hooks?

Comment: It customizes the taskbar. [1UP Bins](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/default.aspx)  Anyhow, still didn't stop the slowness. I exited it, exited several other customization tools, and STILL get a several-minute-pause when I try to delete a file..... this is way off topic by now, so let's stop.

Answer (score 1):

Are the files that you're browsing on a separate hard drive (not your boot drive)? If so, that 5-10 seconds are the drive spinning up and seeking. This is the default behaviour of the power settings in Windows 8.

Comment: 1. Running with only one HDD on system, 2. Problem is in a different drive then boot drive (C: is a boot drive, problem is in E: drive), 3. I am not able to find any of the HDD Spin Behaviour related setting under power setting (Running Windows 8 Pro) please tell me the specific location if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The folder is set to a specific media type so its trying to generate previews.  Do the following:

1. Right click the folder
2. Go to customize
3. Select document from the drop down

[Source](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/download-folder-lot-time-open/) of the above information.

Comment: Can't see "Customize" option after pressing right click on the folder. Moreover the link you have mentioned is specific to the Download Folder, where in my case it happens with other folders.

Answer (score 0):

I also had very serious Windows explorer freezing problem. I Googled the problem and found many fixes such as dynamic tick, hyper-v, updating drivers, re-installing the OS (which was already clean installed), etc, but nothing worked.

I found that Intel rapid storage technology RAID drivers helps to solve this freezing annoyance, I tried it and restarted my lapi but when I clicked on file explorer it again froze for 2-3 seconds. But after 10-15 minutes the freezing problem had just disappeared. Below is the link !

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=2101&DwnldID=22194&lang=eng&iid=dc_rss ( 5MB )

Download your required x64, x86 drivers and install it. It may solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Used [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable IEContextMenu Class running for Symantec, mostly this is the same file that is culprit across all Anti-Virus running on Windows 8

[image]

Answer (score -2):

DO THIS:

1. Open Task Manager
2. Click on Startup tab
3. Disable the following three modules:  (just right click and select disable)

   1. `hkcmd` Module
   2. `igfxtray` Module
   3. `persistence` Module

I don't know if this has any other effect on working of my machine, but it sure as hell
resolved the crashing/ bugging/ hanging issue of my file explorer in Windows 8. Now my explorer 
really runs like a brand new install should.  `:)`

Comment: If you don't know **what** it does, why would you recommend someone else do it?