# Windows 8 Right-click (context) menu hang

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, freeze, context-menu

Recently I reintalled Windows 8. All software that I installed on fresh OS is up to date and Windows 8 compatible.

When I try to open context menu explorer was crashing. I used CCleaner to fix registry errors and after fixing it seems explorer doesn't crash again but when I open context menu it hangs about 5-10 seconds. There are several context menu elements like screenshot below

[image]

that doesn't appear on shellex branch of registry. I can't disable them neither from regedit nor from applications itself like Kaspersky or Nvidia control panell.

How can I fix this hang issue?

Answer (score 1):

Install Glary Utilities from http://www.glarysoft.com/">http://www.glarysoft.com/. It is free for non-commercial use. Once you install it, follow these steps.

**Step 1**: Open Glary Utilities. It will ask for administrative consent. Allow it.
**Step 2**: Go to the *Modules* tab. Then click on *Optimise and Improve*.
**Step 3**: In this tab, click *Context Menu Manager*.

[image]

**Step 4**: Over here, choose which ones you want and enable/disable/delete accordingly.

[image]

Hope that helps your system to run faster!

Comment: I did as shown. This module hasn't fixed problem but registry cleaner found about 5000 errors and fixed. After this my right click works like a charm. The question is, how fresh OS can collect about 5000 errors in registry? And can I trust this type of software?

Comment: It is rated #1 in CNET. That's why I use it. Having said that, don't use it too frequently. Once in a month or two should be enough. And the module didn't show any of your context menu entries? Weird

Comment: Also, installing many softwares successively after a fresh install can cause this. I usually stagger it over a week or two.

Answer (score 1):

Used [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable IEContextMenu Class running for Symantec, mostly this is the same file that is culprit across all Anti-Virus running on Windows 8

[image]

There is also a similar thread [Why does File Explorer hang frequently in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/502894/why-does-file-explorer-hang-frequently-in-windows-8/937992#937992)